# String replace with multiple dropdown search boxes

Tags: php, string, wordpress, replace

I have made a dropdown search option when visitors can select from several words and search for that.

The problem is that with every word extra data is added.

With one word it is

```
/?s=keyword
```

With 2 words it is

```
/?s=keyword&sn=keyword2
```

but it should be

```
/?s=keyword+keyword2
```

The form is as followed

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>">
  <div>
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
Type
<select name='s' id='type' class='postform' >
  <option value='' selected='selected'>All</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="cat">Cat</option>
</select> 

Color
<select name='s' id='color' class='postform' >
  <option value='' selected='selected'>All</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="red">red</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="white">white</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="green">green</option>
</select> 

   <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Is there a way to replace **&sn=** with **+** ?

I have tried

```
$_get = str_replace('&sn=', '+', $_get);
```

But that didn't work.

The working answer was given by Wgaffa and is, but it does not work with IE or Firefox :(

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function add_criteria (el) {
        search = document.getElementById('search_criteria');
        search.value = document.getElementById('type').value + " " + document.getElementById('color').value;
    }
</script>

<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
Type
<select name='' id='type' class='postform' onchange="add_criteria(this);">
  <option value='' selected='selected'>All</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="cat">Cat</option>
</select> 

Color
<select name='' id='color' class='postform' onchange="add_criteria(this);">
  <option value='' selected='selected'>All</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="red">red</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="white">white</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="green">green</option>
</select> 
   <input type="hidden" id="search_criteria" value="" name="s" />
   <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you name the 'search fields':

```
name='criteria[0]'
name='criteria[1]'
name='criteria[2]'
```

So each select box is given the name `criteria[n]`

When you submit the form they should all be wrapped together in a php array `'criteria'`, you can then do:

```
implode('+', $_GET['criteria']);
```

Note you can also name the fields things like `criteria[]` (no number), or `criteria['color']` etc..eg:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>">
  <div>
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
Type
<select name='criteria[type]' id='criteria[type]' class='postform' >
  <option value='' selected='selected'>All</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="cat">Cat</option>
</select> 

Color
<select name='criteria[color]' id='criteria[color]' class='postform' >
  <option value='' selected='selected'>All</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="red">red</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="white">white</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="green">green</option>
</select> 

   <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
  </div>
</form>


    <?

if(isset($_GET['criteria'])){echo implode('+', $_GET['criteria']);}

    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems you made a typo. implode('+', $_GET['criteria']); but I tried it and now it is not showing any results and the url is now

?criteria%5B%22type%22%5D=cat&criteria%5B%22color%22%5D=white

but wordpress search does not work like that. It should be

?s=cat+white

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is an error:

Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed

Comment: The PHP at the end will be invalid and is there as an illustration, you will actually want to include it on the page the form is directed to, probably as if(isset($_GET['criteria'])){implode('+', $_GET['criteria']);} ....that said, is the variable being passed correctly?

Comment: It did fix the implode error. But no they are not being passed correctly.

Comment: Try removing the quotes around the variable names- I've edited the above to illustrate

Comment: How so? I cant replicate any difficulties im afraid

Comment: I think the problem is that Wordpress uses a core based search string /?s=searchstring. So what you have created does not work with that, it just replaces /?s= with ?criteria%5Btype%5D=

Comment: ahhh if you need to build the URL for wordpress purposes (as opposed for your own purposes within wordpress), the JS answer below is your best bet

Comment: I have 0 JS knowledge and cannot find a specific tutorial. Do you have a suggestion where I can find it?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a way to do this with javascript.

Add a hidden textbox with the name "s" and rename the selectboxes.

On each select onchange attribute call a javascript that adds the current selectbox's value to the hidden textbox.

When the form is submitted the hidden box have the value "dog red" and should be passed as ?s=dog+red

I am at work now so dont have time to work out a code sample.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function add_criteria (el) {
        search = document.getElementById('search_criteria');
        search.value = document.getElementById('type').value + " " + document.getElementById('color').value;
    }
</script>

<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="test.html">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
Type
<select name='type' id='type' class='postform' onchange="add_criteria(this);">
  <option value='' selected='selected'>All</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="cat">Cat</option>
</select> 

Color
<select name='color' id='color' class='postform' onchange="add_criteria(this);">
  <option value='' selected='selected'>All</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="red">red</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="white">white</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="green">green</option>
</select> 
   <input type="hidden" id="search_criteria" value="" name="s" />
   <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
  </div>
</form>
```

This may not be crossbrowser compatible (only tested in firefox). And if Wordpress uses jQuery or another javascript library this can be simplified but this is the general idea.

Comment: Thank you. I have zero javascript knowledge, but that is some food for the brain. I am going to do some search on that and hopefully find a solution.

Comment: Could you please point me in the right direction? It's hard to find something without exactly knowing what to look for.

Comment: I am not much of a javascript guru but I have read a bit on jQuery that is a powerful javascript library, check their site out and try to understand it. They have some tutorials there jquery.com. Some low level javascript tutorial http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/index.php and http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Comment: Thank you so much! I took your code, made some changes and it worked!!!! I am so happy. 3 days of searching.

Can I post the working solution under my question?

Comment: You should be able to accept an answer and it will be displayed below your question. Click the little checkmark near the vote up/down arrows to accept this as an answer.

Comment: I have to register first. So I am going to do that and the vote. Thank you

Comment: To add a 3rd row option. Can I add?

search.value = document.getElementById('type').value + " " + document.getElementById('brand').value " " + document.getElementById('color').value;

Comment: yes, correct, but you forgot a + sign in there ...Id('brand').value " " + docume... should have a plus sign between .value and " " or you will get a javascript error. This code may not be the cleanest or best way of doing this but it's up to you to learn and improve from this :)

Comment: Your solution works fine, just not in IE and 85% of my users use IE :( there instead of + it creates &=